# How to link twig template in href?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

How can I link a twig template? Something like this:

`<a href="Events.twig" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg square" role="button">Learn more</a>`

Is there a way to do this or do I have to use URL rewriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is conceptually flawed.  Twig is a templating language, and cannot be rendered as a web page on its own.

You probably don't want to link directly to a `.twig` file (in fact, `.twig` files should not be directly be accessible in your public document root at all)!  Rather, you need some PHP code (either a standalone script, or preferably, a [front controller route](https://learn.userfrosting.com/recipes/creating-a-new-page#defining-a-route)) that renders your template in the context of your application, and returns the fully rendered page at a URL that you have specified.

For example, in the Slim framework, you might do something like:

```
// Render Twig template in route
$app->get('/events', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    return $this->view->render($response, 'events.html.twig');
});

// Run app
$app->run();
```

See [this article](https://learn.userfrosting.com/routes-and-controllers/introduction) for more information on moving away from procedural spaghetti code and thinking in MVC terms.

Answer (score 3):

You can use template controller for this. Just add new route, specify template controller `FrameworkBundle:Template:template` and twig template.

**routes.yml**

```
qwerty:
    path: /qwerty
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template:    Events.twig
```

and change this link to:

```
<a href="{{ path('qwerty') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg square" role="button">Learn more</a>
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/render_without_controller.html

Comment: Stupid question  but where do I put the `routes.yml`? I ried doing this in php from the linked docs but i get `Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "path" function`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `twig` the template will need to be parsed, so you cannot link in the way you have tried. In Symfony 2 you would use something like `{{ path('name_of_path') }}`, you will need to name your route first though.

You can name the route with `name="event"` with Annotations:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * Matches /event exactly
 *
 * @Route("/event", name="event")
 */
public function eventAction()
{
    // ...
}
```

In the twig template link with this:

```
<a href="{{ path('event') }}">Event</a>
```

More info here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#linking-to-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Make another controller action that renders `Events.twig` and link to the respective route using [`path()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path):

```
<a href="{{ path('your_route_name') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg square" role="button">Learn more</a>
```

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#a-simple-controller
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html